# Angular - Karma - ngrx - No provider for Store

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, ngrx

In one of my unit tests, I'm trying to mock @ngrx/store. I've used the technique successfully in another spec file, but when trying to use it in this one, I'm getting an injection error saying `No provider for Store!` Below is the relevant code from the spec file:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
  const emptyState = { opportunities: { list: { items: [], page: 1, total: 0 } } };
  const mockStore = new MockStore<MockAppState>(emptyState);

  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [
      OpportunityListComponent,
      FilledArrayPipe
    ],
    imports: [
      NgFilterListModule,
      FormsModule
    ],
    providers: [
      { provide: OpportunityApi, useValue: apiStub },
      { provide: Store, useValue: mockStore },
      { provide: Router, useValue: routerStub }
    ]
  }).compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
  store = fixture.debugElement.injector.get('Store');
});
```

The only difference between this component and the one that successfully uses the MockStore class is that this component is lazy loaded in its own module separate from AppModule. However, I tried importing StoreModule in that module as well as including StoreModule in the TestBed imports, both to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out my problem was I quoting `Store` in the `fixture.debugElement.injector.get('Store')` call. Removing the quotes fixed my problem.

Answer (score 7):

You should add

```
 imports: [
  ...,
 StoreModule.forRoot(fromRoot.reducers),
],
```

That might help you

Answer (score 6):

With NgRx 7 +, use the `MockStore` like this:

```js
const initialState = {};
  
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [LogsNewComponent],
      providers: [
        provideMockStore({ initialState }),
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
```

Comment: is this NGRX 7+ or 8+? as far as I can see, this isn't working in 7+

Comment: Should be working, it's also in the documentation:
https://ngrx.io/guide/store/testing

Comment: Yea, you're right... I screwed up my imports. I also found [V7 documentation](https://v7.ngrx.io/guide/store/testing) which was useful. Thanks