# No provider for MockState

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am still figuring things out in regards to Angular Unit Testing. I believe this is my first time writing a unit test for a service from scratch. I have copy/pasted code from another and attempted to adapt it. Here's what I have so far:

```
describe('SERVICE -> EditServiceProcedureAuthorizationService', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [HttpClientModule],
            providers: [
                EditServiceProcedureAuthorizationService,
                { provide: Store, useClass: MockStore },
                { provide: AuthorizationsService, useClass: MockAuthorizationsService },
                { provide: ServiceProcedureAuthorizationWorkflowService, useClass: ServiceProcedureAuthorizationWorkflowServiceMock },
                { provide: SpViewAuthorizationDetailsService, useClass: MockSpViewAuthorizationDetailsService }
            ]
        });
    });

    it('should loadAuthorization()', inject(
        [EditServiceProcedureAuthorizationService, Store, AuthorizationsService, ServiceProcedureAuthorizationWorkflowService,
                 SpViewAuthorizationDetailsService],
        fakeAsync(
            (
                editServiceProcedureAuthorizationService: EditServiceProcedureAuthorizationService,
                mockStore: MockStore<AppStore>,
                mockAuthorizationService: MockAuthorizationsService,
                mockServiceProcedureAuthWorkflowService: ServiceProcedureAuthorizationWorkflowServiceMock,
                mockSpViewAuthorizationDetailsService: MockSpViewAuthorizationDetailsService
            ) => {
                const dispatchSpy: Spy = spyOn(mockStore, 'dispatch');
                editServiceProcedureAuthorizationService.loadAuthorization(undefined, undefined);
                expect(dispatchSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

                const memberId = '42';
                const authId = 'auth42';

                editServiceProcedureAuthorizationService.loadAuthorization(memberId, authId);
                expect(dispatchSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
            }
        )
    ));
});
```

Then, when I tried to run this, I got:

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[Store -> MockState]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Store -> MockState]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for MockState!
    at NullInjector.get node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:8894:1)
    at resolveToken node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:9139:1)
    at tryResolveToken node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:9083:1)
    at StaticInjector.get node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:8980:1)
    at resolveToken node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:9139:1)
    at tryResolveToken node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:9083:1)
    at StaticInjector.get node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:8980:1)
    at resolveNgModuleDep node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:21120:1)
    at _createClass node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:21173:1)
    at _createProviderInstance node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:21137:1)
```

I googled this and the closest thing I found was this: [Angular - Karma - ngrx - No provider for Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46687469/angular-karma-ngrx-no-provider-for-store), but don't think it applies.

Really not sure what to try next.

Comment: It seems to me that your `Store` (`MockStore` in this case) relies on a service called `MockState` but in your testing module configuration, you are not providing `MockState`.

Comment: I think @AliF50 is right. You should add this state for your global configuration or create fake store module in your local unit test file and put your state there.

Comment: That was it! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @AliF50, the problem was that MockStore uses MockState. Adding this created a cascade of things that had to be added and created an InjectionToken problem as well.

I finally took the coward's way out and implemented my own TestMock to inject in and everything is working fine.